# I would like to know if there's any better way than mine to solve this code in c#

Tags: c#

this is the problem [enter image description here][1]
class Program
    {
        /* I 'am sorry, but if written this code in french so I will explain the name of variables in English, and what are they doing

```
     and Yes I am aware this code is spaghetti and I would appreciate if there is a better way to write it 

      T is an Array, and cible is a target */



public static int []  getRange(int[] T, int cible)

    {
        // T_indices is an Array of indexes 
        int[] T_indices = new int[10]; 

        //cpt is a counting variable
        int cpt=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
        {
            if(T[i]==cible)
            {
                for (int j = i; j < T.Length; j++)
                {
                    if(T[i]==T[j])
                    {

                        T_indices[cpt] = j;
                        cpt++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
```

//checking if the element doesn't existe so we can return a -1

```
        if(cpt==0)
        {
            T_indices = new int[1];
            T_indices[0] = -1;
            return T_indices;
        }


        else
        {
            //T_indices_Finaux is the final index Array

            int[] T_indices_Finaux = new int[2];
            T_indices_Finaux[0] = T_indices[0];
            // Max doesn't need explanation I guess
            int max = T_indices[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < T_indices.Length; i++)
            {
                if(max< T_indices[i])
                {
                    max = T_indices[i];
                }

            }
            T_indices_Finaux[1] = max;

                if(T_indices_Finaux[0]== T_indices_Finaux[1])
            {
                T_indices_Finaux = new int[1];
                T_indices_Finaux[0] = T_indices[0];

            }


            return T_indices_Finaux;

        }
    }
```

// here we put this spaghetti code to the test suprisenly wroking out

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] T = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8 };

        for (int i = 0; i < getRange(T, 2).Length; i++)
        {

                Console.WriteLine(getRange(T, 2)[i]);

        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a better fit here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com  Though definitely check that community's guidelines first.

Comment: Oh, I have no idea such platform exists, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] T_indices = new int[10];
```

How do you know, that 10 is enough? You do not. This magic number would cause, that the code sometimes works and sometimes it just throws out of range exception. Besides this, the code is okay, but you do it in a bit too complicated way. What you need is basically this

```
public static int[] getRange(int[] T, int cible)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < T.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (T[i] == cible)
        {
            int j = i + 1;
            while (j < T.Length && T[j] == cible) { ++j; }
            --j;
            if (i == j) { return new int[] { i }; }
            return new int[] { i, j };
        }
    }
    return new int[] { -1 };
}
```

And btw. the test code calls the `getRange` function up to three times. You should call it once, store the result array and loop over that array.

Comment: Indeed, I used 10 just for the test and forgot that it may contain more, Thanks Antonin you made it look like a peace of cake

Answer (score 0):

pleas try this :

change `getRange` Method to this :

```
public static List<int> getRange(int[] T, int cible)
            {
                var result=new List<int>();
                var list = T.ToList();
                if(!list.Contains(cible))
                    result.Add(-1);
                else
                {
                    result.Add(list.IndexOf(cible));
                    if (list.Count(x=>x==cible)>1)
                        result.Add(list.LastIndexOf(cible));
                }
                return result;
            }
```

and use it like this :

```
 int[] T = { 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 8 };

   getRange(T, 2).ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

In this solution you will never get an OutOfRange ٍException and also use the native c # method (for get index of a item in array. "`IndexOf`" Instead "`for`") which is much faster and more efficient.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful , I am a bit new to c# and i don't know c# basic methods

Comment: not problem .You have a lot of time to learn it .I'm glad I was able to help you.